# How to detect keydown up and down arrow in same time case Page Dance

Tags: actionscript-3

hello 
 I work at project to build dance game with AS 3.0 control by Page Dance.
 I got problem when player stomp two button in same time. 
How to detect it?

Thank you.

Comment: Post some code on how you are doing the detection.

Comment: I have no idea.
How to detect events with the push of two buttons at once to me.
Do you have ideas how to fix this problem.

Comment: The same way as you would do it otherwise, which is why it would be good with some code. That way we can see what you are doing, and hopefully fix it.

Comment: Here are some of my code.

http://pastebin.com/prg5CZB5

What do you think is it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code in that pastebin, but the problem should not lie in your `onKeys` function.

What does this code do for you, when you press up and down at once?

```
function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    trace("Key event: " + e.keyCode);
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
```

It returns two keycodes instantly for me. If it doesn't for you, your keyboard might not support for those two buttons to be pressed at once (most keyboards have a certain number of keys that are cross-wired to save cost, making it impossible to press them at once).